# Cannot get the text out of node by using XPath

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to get the last movie/series I rated on Letterboxhd by using XPath, then print it. To get the first movie, I found this in HTML: `"<span class="frame-title">Magnolia (1999)</span>"`.
To get the rating of the first movie: `"<span class="rating -tiny -darker rated-6">★★★</span>"`
I know that every time I run this code the rating will be 3 stars, so I only wrote half of it.

Here is what I did:

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {

        let titles = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, 'frame-title')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        let title = titles.iterateNext();

        let ratings = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, ' -tiny')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        let rating = ratings.iterateNext(); 


        return{
            title,
            rating
        }
    });
```

When I run this code, I see "data" is undefined. What am I doing wrong? What should I do instead?

Here is my entire code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    let movieUrl = 'https://letterboxd.com/sdeer/films/';
    
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(movieUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {

        let titles = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, 'frame-title')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        let title = titles.iterateNext();

        let ratings = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, ' -tiny')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        let rating = ratings.iterateNext(); 


        return{
            title,
            rating
        }
    });

    debugger

    console.log(data.title.textContent);
    console.log(data.rating.textContent);

    

    await browser.close();

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of first versus last title I think using `let lastTitle = document.evaluate('descendant::span[contains(@class, "frame-title")][last()]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue` is a better way to read out the last `span` in document order that has the class as `frame-title`.

Nevertheless, it looks as if the web site uses paging so this would give you the last title on the first page.

As for passing DOM nodes around, I think for that you need `page.evaluateHandle` instead of `page.evaluate`.

I think for the the `evaluate` method you can pass JSON on:

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {

        let title = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, 'frame-title')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;
        

        let rating = document.evaluate("//span[contains(@class, ' -tiny')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;


        return {
            title,
            rating
        }
    });
```

Comment: It seems working. Thanks! I just want to ask one more thing.  It actually gets the second most recent movie and its rating. What should I do to make it get the most recent movie?

Comment: I think, if I understand the structure of the site right, you want to load `movieUrl = "https://letterboxd.com/sdeer/films/by/date/";` (instead of `movieUrl = 'https://letterboxd.com/sdeer/films/'`) to get the items ordered by review order and not release date. That seems easier than trying to change the order from JavaScript.